# Cloning html TR is not cloning all cell values

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a html table with a hidden **tr**. The idea is adding more **trs** by clicking one buttton.

```
        <tr class="fila-base hidden">
            <td><input class="form-control input-sm col-xs-1" name="cantidad" id="cantidad" value="0"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" class="form-control input-sm col-xs-2" name="codigoPrincipalProducto" id="codigoPrincipalProducto"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" class="form-control input-sm col-xs-2" name="codigoAuxiliarProducto" id="codigoAuxiliarProducto"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" class="form-control input-sm col-xs-1" name="precioUnitario" id="precioUnitario"/></td>
            <td><input type="number" class="form-control input-sm col-xs-1" name="tDescuento" value="0"/></td>
            <td><input type="number" class="form-control input-sm col-xs-1 " name="precioTotal"/></td>
            <td><input type="number" class="form-control input-sm col-xs-1" name="tIce" id="tIce" value="0"/></td>
            <td class="hidden"><input type="number" class="form-control input-sm col-xs-1" name="tidVP" id="tidVP" value="0"/></td>
            <td id="eliminar-fila"><i class="btn btn-primary btn-xs"><label class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></label> Eliminar</i></td>
        </tr>
```

I have a javascript code that fill all the inputs of this via AJAX. I want to clone the hidden **tr** after I set the values for each of its inputs.

```
            $("#adicionar").on('click', function(event){
            var codP = $("#codP").val();
            var codA = $("#codA").val();
            event.preventDefault();

                $.ajax({
                    url : window.location.pathname + "/precioProducto",
                    type : "POST",
                    contentType : 'application/json',
                    mimeType: 'application/json',
                    dataType : 'json',
                    data :  {codP : codP, codA : codA},

                    success : function(response) {
                        $(".fila-base input#precioUnitario").val(response);
                        alert ($(".fila-base input#precioUnitario").val());
                    },
                    error : function(xhr, status, error) {
                        alert("No se encontró en precio del producto agregado");
                    }
                });

            $(".fila-base input#codigoPrincipalProducto").val(codP);
            $(".fila-base input#codigoAuxiliarProducto").val(codA);

            $("#tablaVenta tbody tr:eq(0)").clone().removeClass('fila-base hidden').appendTo("#tablaVenta tbody");

        });
```

The problem is that when I clone the hidden **tr** all its inputs are cloned except **precioUnitario**. It means I can see a tr with all values and the input **precioUnitario** is empty. However, when I click the button $("#adicionar") again, the second **tr** appears with the value of the first **tr** I added.

Comment: When you alert `$(".fila-base input#precioUnitario").val()`, do you see the value you expect?

Comment: Yes, I see the value.

Comment: Be careful when cloning elements that have the `id` attribute. They are supposed to be unique within the document.

Comment: @Andrew not always the case - I think generally speaking yes I would agree - but you never know what this project may entail

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You set the value of `#precioUnitario` in the `$.ajax`-callback, so you must also append the cloned `<tr>` in the ajax-callback when you want to be sure that the value already has been set when you clone the `<tr>`

The values of the other input's will be cloned, because their values will not be set in the callback